# Simplifying Radical Expression

Tags: radicals

I came across this question in a text book while preparing for return to university. It has been a few years since I flexed the old grey matter and I have not been able to arrive at the solution. Any help would be much appreciated. 
The question is:

> Express the following in the form $ x + y \sqrt{2}$ with x
>   and y rational numbers: $\sqrt[3]{(7+5\sqrt{2})}$

B.O.B gives the answer as:

> $1+\sqrt{2}$

When this expression is cubed it does equal the original expression but I am unsure how to arrive at the solution.

Comment: The practical approach is to expect $x,y$ to be naturals.  Then we are looking for the cube root of about $14.07$, which is between $2$ and $3$.  The only candidate is $1+\sqrt 2$ so try cubing that.  Bingo!

Comment: That's equivalent to noticing that $z^6 - 14z^3-1$ has $z^2-2z-1$ as a factor, which is not all that obvious.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Write $\sqrt[3]{(7+5\sqrt{2})}=x + y \sqrt{2}$, then raise both sides to the third power and solve for $x$ and $y$. You will get:

$x(x^2+6y^2)=7$

$y(3x^2+2y^2)=5$

Then eliminate one of the variables (say $y$) and you will get a polynomial $P(x)=0$. Then you have to look for the rational roots of the polynomial (if such roots exist) with [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Of course in this particular case, you might just observe that $x=y=1$ is solution of the system (which is strongly suggested by the fact that both $5$ and $7$ are prime and both $x^2+6y^2$ and $3x^2+2y^2$ are positive).

Comment: It happens for x=y=1 :P

Comment: It is not easy to get to a polynomial in one variable due to the higher powers here.  You either need to call in Cardano on one of them or do something like $6y^2=\frac 7x-x^2$ but that won't give a polynomial directly.  Without the observation it is a mess.

Comment: Yes, do that, then square the second equation, plug in (you need just the highest power and the free term), solve, verify the solutions. It is not very simple, but not exactly a mess either.

Comment: This answer does indeed provide an algorithmic solution (+1). But @RossMillikan is also right in that the practicality of this approach hinges on having the simplest of all rationals as a root. For example, eliminating $y$ between the equations gives the bicubic in $x\,$: $$256 x^9 - 1344 x^6 + 2460 x^3 - 1372$$ If $x=1$ happened to *not* be an easy root, there would be a whole lot of rational candidates to try by hand.

Comment: P.S. FWIW it works out easier to eliminate the free terms between the equations (multiply the first by $5$, second by $7$, subtract the two) then be left with a homogeneous equation $5 t^3 - 21 t + 30 t - 14 = 0$ where $t = x/y\,$.

Comment: The bicubic simplifies to $64 x^9 - 336 x^6 + 615 x^3 - 343$, which is somewhat simpler. That's not to say that your solution with the homogenous equation is not way better. I wonder in the general case if $\sqrt[3]{a+b\sqrt 2}$ with $a$ and $b$ integers can ever be written as $x+y\sqrt 2$ for non-integer $x$ and/or $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that not every expression of the form $\sqrt[3]{a+b\sqrt2}\quad$can be expressed in the form $c+d\sqrt2.\quad\{a,b,c,d\} \in \text{integers}$

I have a feeling that whoever posed the question to you already knew that a solution existed.